# Incorrect Headers?

Tags: php, header, download, push

**What I'm trying to do:**

Im trying to push a jpg file to download witout user seeing the URL. In this case the file is located at: `http://www.example.com/upload/asdasdsadpokdaspdso/36.jpg`.

**My current code:**

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$download->name.'.jpg"');
readfile($weburl."/upload/".$hiddenpassage."/".$download->link);
```

**My vars / db values:**

```
 $weburl = "http://wwww.example.com";
 $hiddenpassage = "asdasdsadpokdaspdso";

 $download->link = 36.jpg //not a var, just drom db.
 $download->name = The First Test Product //not a var, just from db.
```

**The problem:**

When I get the download I open it and I get the following error:

> ```
> The file “The First Test Product (28).jpg” could not be opened.
> It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.
> ```

**Renaming .jpg to .txt:**

http://pastebin.com/K9NGL5RP

Most of that is the content of the page I downloaded it from.

Comment: Is this download code on the same page that calls it? You need to make sure nothing gets outputted except the image contents, meaning you should end the code with an "exit;" and make sure nothing gets outputted before it.

Comment: @BaileyHerbert Yes it's the same page. I've added exit; after readfile(); and still same error.

Comment: Then that's what the issue is. Make the download script a separate php file. You're obviously not taking any measures to prevent the page from displaying its contents inside a .jpg download.

Comment: @BaileyHerbert I've just made a new php file named download-image.php and then require_once('download-image.php'); in the function (this gets called to download page). I also made sure I had exit; in the end of my download-image.php file, still same error.

Comment: No, that won't work. You don't understand. Your page is also outputting its contents BEFORE the image is downloaded, so you're going to continue to receive errors until you make sure that **only** the image's data is outputted. Just look at what it's returning: http://pastebin.com/K9NGL5RP - do you not understand what's going on? You cannot expect the computer to be able to separate the image's data from the webpage's text.

Comment: @BaileyHerbert Thanks, you helped me fix it. I've just edited my current code: ob_end_clean(); /*the code I have*/ exit();

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the whole header (untested). Specially the Content-Length.:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$download->name.'.jpg');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($weburl."/upload/".$hiddenpassage."/".$download->link));
readfile($weburl."/upload/".$hiddenpassage."/".$download->link);
```

Hope this helps.